# Open Virtual Switch for bridging Physical network On Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: network-bridge, vlan

I am proof of concept for a client, the requirement are the following:

Stretch across 2 site the ERP network (stretched VLAN), this is needed due to dated machinery that have to talk to a particular IP address; we cannot change the address of the ERP HA as the industrial machinery have it hard coded in it.

What I have is the following set up:

2 Ubuntu server 16.04 3 NIC for each server OVS version 2.5.5

Servers configurations:

They are named respectively OVS1 and OVS2 The servers network par have 1 NIC for management (those configuration identity are mirrored across the two servers, IP addressing is different) 1 NIC is assigned to a OVS-bridge AB100, one physical port is assigned to this bridge 1 NIC is assigned to a OVS-bridge OUTBOUND, one physical port is assigned to this bridge

The bridge are address and configures as follow on each server:

On OVS1 Bridge AB100 have an IP address of 10.1.1.201 On OVS1 Bridge AB100 have a VXLAN100 with remote IP 172.29.0.2 On OVS1 Bridge AB100 have a GRE0 with remote IP 172.29.0.4 On OVS1 Bridge OUTBOUND have an IP address of 172.24.0.1

On OVS2 Bridge AB100 have an IP address of 10.1.1.202 On OVS1 Bridge AB100 have a VXLAN100 with remote IP 172.29.0.1 On OVS1 Bridge AB100 have a GRE0 with remote IP 172.29.0.3 On OVS1 Bridge OUTBOUND have an IP address of 172.24.0.2

OVS1 interface eth0 is for management OVS2 interface eth0 is for management OVS1 interface eth1 is in bridge AB100 OVS2 interface eth1 is in bridge AB100 OVS1 interface eth2 is in bridge OUTBOUND OVS2 interface eth2 is in bridge OUTBOUND

Physical connectivity:

OVS1 interface eth0, management on physical management switch1 OVS2 interface eth0, management on physical management switch1 OVS1 interface eth1, bridge AB100 on physical management switch2 OVS2 interface eth1, bridge AB100 on physical management switch2 OVS1 interface eth2, bridge OUTBOUND on physical management switch3 OVS2 interface eth2, bridge OUTBOUND on physical management switch3

Interface eth0 are not part of any OVS switch, they are currently working and are the medium where i can SSH into and manage the devices.

What is connected to them:

OVS1 interface eth1, bridge AB100 on physical management switch2, Mint desktop with IP 10.1.1.2 OVS2 interface eth1, bridge AB100 on physical management switch2, Fedora desktop with IP 10.1.1.3 Secondary IP address 10.1.1.254, which will vary depending which one is the active, but for this example lets leave it on 10.1.1.2 One of the device will have a secondary IP address of 10.1.1.254 which is the IP address where all the factory devices connect to.

Issue:

Connectivity from the two desktop to the local bridge AB100, is successful and they can ping each others. Issuing a ping to one of the IP 172.29.0.1 or 172.29.0.2 respectively inverse not successful Issuing a ping to one if the IP 172.24.0.1 or 172.24.0.2 respectively from their own OVS not successful

Looking at the ARP- a it can see the IP address but not the MAC address of the respective OVS from the OUTGOING Bridge Looking at the ovs-appctl fdb/show OUTBOUND it can see the MAC address

The result should be that the two Desktop should be able to ping each other across the VXLAN or the GRE tunnel, but I am at the stage that not basic connectivity is in place.

Any help and suggestion would be appreciated.

Regards

MEMA